# My 2 Year Old Chihuahua cries loudly after I leave

Tags: dogs, anxiety

I have a 2 year old Chihuahua (Oli) that has been through the ringer. I got him in June of 2017 so not even a year ago. He attached to me very quickly. He was not potty trained and did not have any manners with people food.

We got those two issues under control pretty fast.

I unexpectedly ended up going through a divorce in November in which I got all 3 of our pups. They all get along so well it wasn't fair to split them. With the divorce, my husband moved out, then me and the pups were living at my parents for 3 weeks in between apartments, then we finally got into my new apartment on Jan 16th. Since we left our old apartment and moved into my parents, Oli has struggled with me leaving the house. He doesn't tear up anything, he just cries very loudly and for a long long time. I am not in a position to let him just cry with there being so many people at the new complex I am living at. Also, he is fine with me leaving first thing in the morning, but if I come home for lunch or leave after I am home from work, he freaks. Besides completely enabling him and just staying home when I get home and not coming home to walk them at lunch, I don't know what to do.

I need help!

I have a thunder jacket for him that doesn't seem to help.
My sister lives there also and that doesn't calm him down quickly it's after about 30 minutes he calms down.
I get all 3 pups up and walk them before work then feed them then they go back to bed.

Any help would be great! 
Alexis

Comment: Just one quick thing to clear up: so your dog is asleep when you leave?